# mutate multiple columns generated with one function?

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I have a data frame with any number of variables, plus 3 variables for an RGB color. I want to convert the RGB color to LAB, and add these to the data frame. Here's the ugly code:

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1:10),red=runif(10),green=runif(10),blue=runif(10))
df <- cbind(df,convertColor(subset(df,select=c("red","green","blue")),from="sRGB",to="Lab"))
```

It would be great if mutate could generate multiple variables with a single call; e.g. (pseudocode):

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1:10),red=runif(10),green=runif(10),blue=runif(10))
df <- df %>% mutate(list("L","a","b") = convertColor(cbind(red,green,blue),from="sRGB",to="Lab"))
```

Is there a similar approach using dplyr?

Comment: A quick comment, please avoid `df` as a name for a data.frame. `df` is already a R function. You can use `DF` instead.

Comment: I'm not sure why the first code is 'ugly' - it requires less typing than `dplyr` does?! Also, you could simplify like `cbind(df, convertColor(df[c("red","green","blue")], from="sRGB", to="Lab"))`

Comment: @Pascal Unless you're playing around with F densities and distributions, I don't think using `df` for a quick example causes much harm...

Comment: @PeterDee From my point of view, we should discourage to overwrite existing function, even for a quick example. But yes, here, it won't cause much harm.

Comment: @Pascal while theoretically dangerous, using names for objects that are identical to function names will very rarely cause any issues in practice - creating the object doesn't stop you from being able to use the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want some syntactic sugar, you can use this code:

```
df %>% 
  select(red,green,blue) %>% 
  convertColor(from="sRGB",to="Lab") %>% 
  cbind(df,.)
```

Comment: I know very little of `dplyr`, but is the in-house `bind_cols` preferred to `cbind` ?

Comment: `bind_cols` is a new thing in `dplyr` (http://blog.rstudio.org/2015/01/09/dplyr-0-4-0/), and I haven't explored it yet

Comment: @thelatemail It might need data.frames as input.  The output from `convertColor` is matrix.  So perhaps `df %>% select(red,green,blue) %>% convertColor(from="sRGB",to="Lab") %>% as.data.frame() %>% bind_cols(df, .)`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid needless copying of your data, this is the `data.table` syntax, to add the new columns by modifying your data in place:

```
library(data.table)
dt = as.data.table(df)

dt[, c('L', 'a', 'b') := as.data.table(convertColor(.SD, from = 'sRGB', to = 'Lab'))
   , .SDcols = c('red', 'green', 'blue')]
```